# not able to get files when there is more than one isolated storage folder

Tags: c#, isolatedstorage

I have 2 isolated storage folder for my admin user,

[image]

In top folder I have a file which I want to grab. I'm using below code to calculate the path for Isolated Storage,

```
var path = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly().GetType().GetField("m_RootDir", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly()).ToString()
```

Now this will always give me path for bottom folder (picture above) whereas my file reside under top folder.

Is there other way to grab the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use reflection for getting files.
This document may be helpful : 
[How to: Find Existing Files and Directories in Isolated Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-find-existing-files-and-directories-in-isolated-storage)